# Random leather badge / tag

Tags: luggage

I recently bought a TravelPro suitcase and there's a small piece of leather sewn to the front. Why is this here? What purpose does it serve?

[image: leather badge]

Comment: If it doesn't have a slot on any side to slip in a hidden ID card, then maybe it is a place for them to emboss a travelers initials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called a "monogram patch" and is for putting initials (or some other personalized mark) on, mainly as a way of differentiating your bag from all of the other similar looking ones.

Tumi are best known for this, and in fact have an page on their website regarding it - see [here](http://www.tumi.com/personalization), although as you've discovered a number of other brands of luggage do the same thing on at least some of their products.

[image]

Comment: The link does not work for me. Redirects to http://intl.tumi.com/